# How to pass values via href to new popup window

Tags: php, popup, href

I want have a variable which i want to pass from parent page to popup window.

Trying below but not getting required output on popup window.

Parent page:

```
<a href=cancellation_policy.php?d=",urlencode($vendor_id),"  onclick="window.open('cancellation_policy.php','newwindow', 'width=700, height=450'); return false; "><?php echo "<h10>(Cancellation policy)</h10>";}?></a>
```

On popup window:

```
<?php echo $vendor_id = $_GET['$d']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

During your JavaScript call to the Popub, you use the cancellation_policy.php without any parameters. So `echo $vendor_id = $_GET['$d'];` will not echo anything. Also you called your parameter in the URL 'd' and not '$d'.

You either have the possibility to add them to the JavaScript call:

```
window.open('cancellation_policy.php?d=[...]'...
```

or by having a JavaScript function that uses the href attribute of the a tag to build a complete URL and then use `window.open(...)`. The first Idea is probably the faster solution.

**Edit:**
For better explanation: The window.open method does not use the href attribute of your a-element. So the there configured parameter 'd' will not be used here.

Comment: no, it would be $_GET['d'], btw probably you should use better variable names. Single characters usually lead to losing the overview...

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function in any tag and have the function open the window.  Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
  window.open('cancellation_policy.php?d=' + urlencode($vendor_id),'newwindow', 'width=700, height=450'); 
}
</script>

<a onclick="javascript:test()"><?php echo "<h10>(Cancellation policy)</h10>";}?></a>
```

Comment: Hi Dmitri K, Need some href in the last line

Comment: Thanks, but <a> tag without an href is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `href` as you need it then such `onclick` to make the link open in new window:

```
<a href=".." onclick="window.open(this.href, 'newwindow', 'width=700,height=450'); return false; ">
```

The `this.href` will simply take whatever you have in the *href* attribute, no need to repeat it.